# Limiting the Domain of a Function

Tags: function-construction, piecewise

Currently, I am trying to plot (using Mathematica) the following function:

$$f(t) = \begin{cases} 0, & 0<t<1 \\ 1, & 1<t<2 \end{cases} $$

And, to try to plot this, I did some readings on this StackExchange regarding "Conditions". I did give it a try and for some reason, it isn't working.

Below is my code:

**f[t_1 /; 0 < t < 1] := 0**

**f[t_2 /; 1 < t < 2] := 1**

**Plot[{t_1, t_2}, {t, -10, 10}]**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not use `Piecewise[]`? `Plot[Piecewise[{{0, 0 < t < 1}, {1, 1 < t < 2}},Indeterminate], {t, -10, 10}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
f[t_] := 0 /; 0 < t < 1
```

see also Step and PieceWise in the documentation.

Comment: Also `f[t_] /; 0 < t < 1 := 0`.  I think it is the same.